# actionscript problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, variables

```
package com.rubenswieringa.interactivemindmap {

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    import mx.flash.UIMovieClip;

    public class NodeRendererBase extends UIMovieClip {

        private var _transparent:Boolean = false;
        private var _text:String = "";

        private static const NUM_DEPTHS:uint = 5;

        public function NodeRendererBase ():void {
            this.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            // set settings for all TextFields:
            var i:int;
            var textField:TextField;
            for (i=1; i<=NodeRendererBase.NUM_DEPTHS; i++){
                textField = this.getChildByName("textField"+i) as TextField;
                textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            }
        }

        public function setSkinByID (id:String):Boolean {
            this.gotoAndStop(id);
            if (this.currentLabel != id){
                return false;
            }
            this.applyText();
            return true;
        }

        public function setSkinByDepth (depth:int):Boolean {
            return this.setSkinByID("depth"+depth);
        }

        public function get text ():String {
            return this._text
        }
        public function set text (value:String):void {
            if (this._text == value){
                return;
            }
            this._text = value;
            this.applyText();
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        private function applyText ():void {
            var i:int;
            // this method is not needed if the item-renderer is not displaying a certain depth:
            if (this.currentLabel.slice(0, 5) != "depth"){
                return;
            }
            // textField (TextField):
            var textField:TextField;
            for (i=1; i<=NodeRendererBase.NUM_DEPTHS; i++){
                textField = this.getChildByName("textField"+i) as TextField;
                if (i.toString() == this.currentLabel.slice("depth".length)){
                    textField.text = this._text;
                }else{
                    textField.text = "";
                }
            }
            // background (MovieClip):
            var background:DisplayObject;
            //for (i=1; i<=NodeRendererBase.NUM_DEPTHS; i++){
            for (i=1; i<=NodeRendererBase.NUM_DEPTHS; i++){
                background = this.getChildByName("background_mc"+i);
                if (i.toString() == this.currentLabel.slice("depth".length)){
                    textField = this.getChildByName("textField"+i) as TextField;
                    background.height = textField.height + (textField.y - background.y) * 2;
                }else{
                    background.visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public function setColor (index:int):void {
            var background:DisplayObject = this.getChildByName("background_mc"+this.currentLabel.slice("depth".length));
            background['gotoAndStop'](index);
        }

        public function get transparent ():Boolean {
            return this._transparent;
        }
        public function set transparent (value:Boolean):void {
            if (this._transparent == value){
                return;
            }
            this._transparent = value;
            // set visuals:
            var newFilters:Array = (value) ? [new BlurFilter(3, 3)] : [];
            this.filters = newFilters;
        }

    }

}
```

If I change `private static const NUM_DEPTHS:uint = 5;` to anything other than 5 (I am trying to increase its value) the script fails. Any inputs why?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"?  What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: The generated swf has a background, and that is all it has! Values lower than 5 yield this: 0: black bubbles, 1 white bubbles, 2: first bubble is ok rest have strange rendering 3: 4: 5: graduate up likewise, but if you excede 5 everything is blank

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue lies here:

```
for (i=1; i<=NodeRendererBase.NUM_DEPTHS; i++){
    textField = this.getChildByName("textField"+i) as TextField;
    textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
}
```

Basically, when you increase the value of `NUM_DEPTHS`, you're telling this loop that there will be more than 5 textfields.  Presumably this isn't the case, or you've created more and not named them correctly (`textField6`, `textField7` etc), and so the call to `getChildByName()` will fail after the fifth iteration.

Comment: http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/interactivemindmap/source/

Comment: @sam, sorry but how is your link relevant to the answer? what are you trying to say?

Comment: I was wondering if looking at the rest of the files might help. I finally did figure out what the problem was. The flashcomponents.swc file accompanying this contains only five layers. That was the limiting factor. I will need to add my custom layers if i want to support more than 5 nodes of different colors! Thanks for looking into it.